# Emacs mode 1, 2 and t (what t stands for)?

Tags: emacs

For instance, `global-linum-mode 1` enables line numbers `global-linum-mode 0` disables line numbers, what `global-linum-mode t` would do? and I've seen another parameter: `nil`. What do they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t` and `nil` in boolean context are the (Emacs) Lisp truth values. `nil` is false. Any non-nil value is considered to be true, but `t` is customarily used. [Source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#nil-and-t).

As for `global-linum-mode`, any non-negative parameter will enable it, including `t`, `"foo"`,... etcetera.

For such questions it is very useful to play in the scratch buffer with elisp: type your expression there and press `C-j`.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is true, `nil` is false.